# Visitor pattern: avoid casting for simple expression calculator

Tags: c#, generics, interpreter, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to design an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) for a simple language interpreter. To avoid casting during evaluation, I've tried to use generics (this technique is described more fully [here](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64040/gadtoop.pdf)).

My base type is `Exp<T>` and I use `IExpression` as a grouping interface (see below -- it will be what evaluation returns).

```
public interface IExpression
{
}

public abstract class Exp<T> : IExpression
{ 
    public abstract U Accept<U>(IVisitor<U> visitor);

    public IExpression Eval()
    {
        return this.Accept<IExpression>(new EvaluationVisitor());
    }
}

public class Lit : Exp<int>
{
    public int value;

    public Lit(int value) 
    { 
        this.value = value; 
    }

    public override U Accept<U>(IVisitor<U> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public class Plus : Exp<int>
{
    public Exp<int> e1, e2;

    public Plus(Exp<int> e1, Exp<int> e2)
    { 
        this.e1 = e1; 
        this.e2 = e2; 
    }

    public override U Accept<U>(IVisitor<U> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

I had hoped that I could now use the [visitor design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_p) to evaluate the tree. Evaluation of a `Plus` expression, however results in an ugly cast. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
public interface IVisitor<T>
{
    T Visit(Lit exp);
    T Visit(Plus exp);
}

public class EvaluationVisitor : IVisitor<IExpression>
{
    public IExpression Visit(Lit exp)
    {
        return exp;
    }

    public IExpression Visit(Plus exp)
    {
        var v1 = (Lit)exp.e1.Accept<IExpression>(this);
        var v2 = (Lit)exp.e2.Accept<IExpression>(this);
        return new Lit(v1.value + v2.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that `Exp` is short for `Expression`, and `Lit` is short for `Literal`?

Comment: @ClickRick Yes, you are correct (this code was copied and modified from the Microsoft article link).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to use the return value from `Visit`, which will always require the cast, consider giving your visitor some state:

```
public class EvaluationVisitor : IVisitor<IExpression>
{
    public IExpression Visit(Lit exp)
    {
        mValueStack.Push( exp.value );
        return exp;
    }

    public IExpression Visit(Plus exp)
    {
        exp.e1.Accept<IExpression>( this );
        exp.e2.Accept<IExpression>( this );
        int v2 = mValueStack.Pop();
        int v1 = mValueStack.Pop();
        mValueStack.Push( v1 + v2 );
        return new Lit( v1 + v2 );
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            if( mValueStack.Count != 1 )
            {
                // Malformed expression, could throw an exception or something
            }
            return mValueStack.Peek();
        }
    }

    private readonly Stack<int> mValueStack = new Stack<int>();
}
```

You could also just have your `EvaluationVisitor` return the actual value from the `Visit` method:

```
public class EvaluationVisitor : IVisitor<int>
{
    public int Visit(Lit exp)
    {
        return exp.value;
    }

    public int Visit(Plus exp)
    {
        int v1 = exp.e1.Accept<int>( this );
        int v2 = exp.e2.Accept<int>( this );
        return v1 + v2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add another type, `If<T>` which represents conditional execution? I don't just want an `int` visitor, I need something more general (this is why I use `IExpression` as the visitor's return type).

Comment: @rookie In that case go with the first option and give the visitor state.  In my experience trying to use generic return values in the visitor pattern is rarely a good idea, it just gets messy in a hurry.  Traditionally, visitors "return" values by storing said value in a member that can be accessed by the caller.  This is also how additional parameters can be "passed" into the visit methods as well.

Comment: Another option is to add another visitor type for evaluating the condition since that's really a boolean evaluation.  You're gonna have a bad time if you try to have one evaluator that can evaluate any expression into an arbitrary type.

Comment: I think the best result comes when a the `Accept`/`Visit` methods are void methods. If we do this, and have the `IVisitor` implementation just mutate some state rather than return a value, we can give the `Accept` method any implementation of `IVisitor`. This allows us to implement formatting, type-checking, and other algorithms as visitors, simply by implementing `IVisitor`. This level of interchangeability is far better than the original implementation in question and I think more in the spirit of what the algorithm actually tries to achieve.